# Unique word of specific length

Tags: shell, unix

I used this command to list the words of length 2

```
tr ' ' '\n' < cca.txt | grep '^.\{2\}$'
```

but it prints duplicated words as it occurs multiple times.

How I can make it prints list of words of length 2 without duplication?

sample of input

```
" إن اللقاء هو فقط عرض لفيلم مسجل عن محاضرة له سابقة وأنهم يتوقعون جمهورا كبيرا لها 
ثم التقيت بمبشر قضى أكثر ردح من حياته في بلاد الشام يدأب لإنشا"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply pipe to `sort -u`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < cca.txt | grep '^.\{2\}$' | sort -u
```

Or its simpler form:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < cca.txt | grep '^..$' | sort -u
```

However, consider this sample text:

```
## Todo list with priorities

- An option: priority, time, or mix
- a: Topics
- b: categories
```

With your original solution, things like `##` and `a:` will match which are not really words. You could be more strict like this:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < cca.txt | grep '\<..\>' | sort -u
```

This way only `An` and `or` will match.

Finally, if your version of `grep` has the `-o` flag, then you can do this without `tr`:

```
grep -o '\<..\>' cca.txt | sort -u
```

You could also do everything in a single `awk` proces:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /\<..\>/) u[$i]=1 } END { for (i in u) print i }' cca.txt
```

**UPDATE**

I see that the `\<` doesn't work well with arabic, at least not in my system (Debian/Linux).  However, the first solution I proposed seems to work, for this input:

```
إن اللقاء هو فقط عرض لفيلم مسجل عن محاضرة له
سابقة وأنهم يتوقعون جمهورا كبيرا لها 
ثم التقيت بمبشر قضى أكثر ردح من حياته
في بلاد الشام يدأب لإنشا
إن اللقاء هو فقط عرض لفيلم مسجل عن محاضرة له
سابقة وأنهم يتوقعون جمهورا كبيرا لها 
ثم التقيت بمبشر قضى أكثر ردح من حياته
في بلاد الشام يدأب لإنشا
```

I get:

```
إن
ثم
عن
في
له
من
هو
```

Which all look 2-letters and unique.

Comment: when using | sort -u  it list part of word not vomplete word! why?

Comment: @user2999200 I don't understand what you mean. Maybe you can explain in more detail. Have you tried all my solutions?

Comment: Yes i did and all of it not working to list words of length 2 without duplication

Comment: @user2999200 please post a sample input in your question to demonstrate the problem.